# Who is the medium sized Robin?

Tags: dc, character-identification, the-new-52, robin

The image below is from New 52 Batman #15.
I am wondering who the medium sized "Robin" (circled in yellow) is.
He is probably not called Robin, but you get the point,
red and black color theme, young male.

[image: Image from New 52]

From other New 52, comics I have been reading I have seen him around a few times. But not named, and I don't know what he does.

I know:

- The man in grey is Batman, aka Bruce Wayne, star of "Batman", "Detective Comics" and I think 1 or 2 other New 52 lines.
- The lady is BatGirl, aka Barbara Gordan. Star of her own series, "Batgirl"
- The smallest "robin" is actually Robin, aka Damian. Is the main character of "Batman and Robin"
- The biggest "robin", is Nightwing, aka Richard Greyson I think a former "Robin, the boy wonder" but now grown-up and has his own comics "Nightwing".

But who is the other one is, or what comic does he mostly appears in?

I also don't know who red-masked dude is, but I am less interested in him.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is Tim Drake, the third Robin.  His role in DC's *The New 52* is as [Red Robin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tim_Drake#Red_Robin_(2009%E2%80%932011)):

[image: Tim Drake Red Robin]

The man in the red full mask is Jason Todd, the second Robin, as [Red Hood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hood):

[image]